# Mini pager work with ajax but not full pager?

Tags: ajax, paging

I don't know if someone has ever expected this error but i can't find "why" it's not working.

In the same page, i have 2 blocks. Each block represent a different view.

The first have mini pager, the second, full pager.

Mini pager is working well, full pager reload the page each time (Yes, i have Use AJAX to Yes).

The only differences i can see are into the HTML (The mini pager UL have class "pager" and the LI have class "pager-prev" and "pager-next"). In the full pager, UL have no class and LI have classes "next" and "prev".

Full pager is suppose to use ajax?

Thanks for your help folks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a theme issue, try switching to Bartik and seeing if the issue is resolved. For example Omega provides its own theme() function for full and mini pagers.

The class pager is required on the UL element for pager AJAX to work properly. Review your theme and make sure it is properly theming the full pager, or open an issue on the Drupal.org project page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues with multiple Views pagers on the same page, try adjusting the "Pager ID" ( e.g "1" ) in the View pager settings:

[image: view pager settings screenshot]

Comment: Hey,thanks for this i've already did it. I can now page them separately, but, it don't solve my bigger problem, why full-pager doesn't work with Ajax but mini-pager work =\